# Leveraging Spell Checker on local machine?

Tags: python, node.js, string, spell-checking

I notice that common applications on a given machine (Mac, Linux, or Windows) have their respective spell checkers.  Everything from various IDE, to MS Word/Office, to Note taking software.

I am trying to utilize the built in utility of our respective machines in order to analyze strings for syntactic correctness.  It seems that I cant just use what is on the machine and would have to likely download a dictionary in which to compare against.

I was not sure if there was a better way to accomplish this.  I was looking at trying to do things locally, but I was not opposed to doing api or curl requests to determine if the words in a string are spelled correctly.

I was looking at:

- LanguageTool (*hello wrold* failed to return an error)
- Google's tbproxy seems to not be functional
- Dictionary / Meriam-Webster require api keys for automation.

I was looking at Node packages and noticed spell checker modules which encapsulate wordlists as well.

Is there a way to utilize the built in machine dictionaries at all, or would it be ideal if I download a dictionary / wordlist to compare against?

I am thinking a wordlist might be best bet, but i didnt want to reinvent the wheel.  What have others done to accomplish similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tagged as both NodeJS and Python. This is the NodeJS specific part, but I imagine it's very similar to python.

---

Windows (from Windows 8 onward) and Mac OS X do have built-in spellchecking engines.

- Windows: The "Windows Spell Checking API" is a C/C++ API. To use it with NodeJS, you'll need to create a binding.
- Mac OS X: "NSSpellChecker" is part of AppKit, used for GUI applications. This is an Objective-C API, so again you'll need to create a binding.
- Linux: There is no "OS specific" API here. Most applications use Hunspell but there are alternatives. This again is a C/C++ library, so bindings are needed.

Fortunately, there is already a module called [spellchecker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spellchecker) which has bindings for all of the above. This will use the built-in system for the platform it's installed on, but there are multiple drawbacks:

1) Native extensions must be build. This one has finished binaries via node-pre-gyp, but these need to be installed for specific platforms. If you develop on Mac OS X, run `npm install` to get the package and then deploy your application on Linux (with the `node_modules`-directory), it won't work.

2) Using build-in spellchecking will use defaults dictated by the OS, which might not be what you want. For example, the used language might be dictated by the selected OS language. For a UI application (for example build with Electron) this might be fine, but if you want to do server-side spellchecking in languages other than the OS language, it might prove difficult.

---

At the basic level, spellchecking some text boils down to:

1. Tokenizing the string (e.g. by spaces)
2. Checking every token against a list of known correct words
3. (Bonus) Gather suggestions for wrong tokens and give the user options.

You can write part 1 yourself. Part 2 and 3 require a "list of known correct words" or a dictionary. Fortunately, there is a format and tools to work with it already:

- [simple-spellchecker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-spellchecker) can work with `.dic`-files.
- [nspell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nspell) is a JS implementation of Hunspell, complete with its own dictionary packages.
- Additional Dictionaries can be found for example in [this repo](https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries)

With this, you get to choose the language, you don't need to build/download any native code and your application will work the same on every platform. If you're spellchecking on the server, this might be your most flexible option.

Comment: Pretty informative. I think this might give me a sound result.  My desired use case is to do automated bulk spell checking for our json strings.  It sounds like using nspell might be a sound option and will look into it more.  Ideally, I am trying to make a git gating mechanism which validates our string files, so it would be on our server.   Do you happen to have a simple sample how-to given an array of words?  I am going to research to find an explicit resolution / how-to to implement one of the listed options

Comment: If you're using `nspell`, just iterate the words and call `correct(word)` for every one. The method returns a boolean indicating if the word is spelled correctly. For your usecase however I think it might be beneficial to make an additional dictionary with any project-specific jargon, as the basic dictionary might generate quite a few false-positive hits.

Comment: Im going to give you the Checkmark and thumbs up momentarily, but i will submit an answer which gives an explicit step by step on what to do with nspell etc.

Answer (score 3):

The Credit is going to Lukas Knuth.  I want to give an explicit how to for using dictionary and nspell.

Install The following 2 dependancies:

```
npm install nspell dictionary-en-us
```

Here is a Sample File I wrote in order to solve the problem.

```
// Node File

//  node spellcheck.js [path]
//  path: [optional] either absolute or local path from pwd/cwd

//  if you run the file from within Seg.Ui.Frontend/ it works as well.
//    node utility/spellcheck.js
//  OR from the utility directory using a path:
//    node spellcheck.js ../src/assets/i18n/en.json

var fs = require("fs");
var dictionary = require("dictionary-en-us");
var nspell = require("nspell");
var process = require("process");
// path to use if not defined.
var path = "src/assets/i18n/en.json"

let strings = [];
function getStrings(json){
    let keys = Object.keys(json);
    for (let idx of keys){
        let val = json[idx];
        if (isObject(val)) getStrings(val);
        if (isString(val)) strings.push(val)
    }
}

function sanitizeStrings(strArr){
    let set = new Set();
    for (let sentence of strArr){
        sentence.split(" ").forEach(word => {
            word = word.trim().toLowerCase();
            if (word.endsWith(".") || word.endsWith(":") || word.endsWith(",")) word = word.slice(0, -1);
            if (ignoreThisString(word)) return;
            if (word == "") return;
            if (isNumber(word)) return;
            set.add(word)
        });
    }
    return [ ...set ];
}

function ignoreThisString(word){
    // we need to ignore special cased strings, such as items with
    //  Brackets, Mustaches, Question Marks, Single Quotes, Double Quotes
    let regex = new RegExp(/[\{\}\[\]\'\"\?]/, "gi");
    return regex.test(word);
}

function spellcheck(err, dict){
    if (err) throw err;
    var spell = nspell(dict);
    let misspelled_words = strings.filter( word => {
        return !spell.correct(word)
    });
    misspelled_words.forEach( word => console.log(`Plausible Misspelled Word: ${word}`))
    return misspelled_words;
}

function isObject(obj) { return obj instanceof Object }
function isString(obj) { return typeof obj === "string" }
function isNumber(obj) { return !!parseInt(obj, 10)}

function main(args){
    //node file.js path
    if (args.length >= 3) path = args[2]
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
        console.log(`The path does not exist: ${process.cwd()}/${path}`);
        return;
    }
    var content = fs.readFileSync(path)
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    getStrings(json);
    // console.log(`String Array (length: ${strings.length}): ${strings}`)
    strings = sanitizeStrings(strings);
    console.log(`String Array (length: ${strings.length}): ${strings}\n\n`)

    dictionary(spellcheck);
}
main(process.argv);
```

This will return a subset of strings to look at and they may be misspelled or false positives.

A false positive will be denoted as:

- An acronym
- non US English variants for words
- Un recognized Proper Nouns,  Days of the Week and Months for example.
- Strings which contain parenthese.  This can be augmented out by trimming them off the word.

Obviously, this isnt for all cases, but i added an ignore this string function you can leverage if say it contains a special word or phrase the developers want ignored.

This is meant to be run as a node script.